# AVFoundation - efficient trimming with and instant preview with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

So I'm trying to use AVFoundation to trim videos. Just like in an iMovie, I have a movie made from several clips. Now, I want to trim few of those clips and provide instant preview of the result using AVPlayer.

Right now, when user trimmed a video, I've exported entire movie using AVAssetExportSession and played it.
As you can imagine, it's not the perfect solution as exporting videos takes too much time.

Is there any better way to achieve that?

In short, what I want to achieve:
- Hey AVPlayer. Here are all 10 clips, play them one after the other, but remember to skip 5 first seconds of the third clip, and skip 2 last seconds of the fifth clip.

Comment: Take a look at `AVMutableComposition`, since it's an `AVAsset` it can be more or less directly played in an `AVPlayer`.

Comment: @David , thanks! I didn't notice that AVComposition is also AVAsset. Thanks!